# Output based on conditional github action matrix build

Tags: github-actions, cicd

I am running a below job in github actions (sample).

```
jobs:
  gradle:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        jdk: [11, 14]
    runs-on: [linux]

  steps:
    - name: Checkout Repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    ...
    - name: gradle Build
      uses: abc_workflow@v1
      with:
        java-version: ${{ matrix.jdk }}
```

I want to implement a condition, where if build based on jdk version 11 is passing, it should pass the result of overall workflow and if build based on jdk version 11 is failing, it should fail the overall workflow, irrespective of the build result of version jdk 14.

Can someone please help with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell it to not fail when a specific matrix job fails:

```yaml
jobs:
  gradle:
    continue-on-error: ${{ matrix.jdk == 14 }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        jdk: [11, 14]
```

See [*Handling failures*](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs#handling-failures) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin for your answer. Is it possible it have it generic like for the first element in matrix it will always check for the result and ignore the elements for 2nd or 3rd element of given matrix? Any guidance would be appreciated!!

Comment: @new_bie I don't think that's possible by referencing something like an index, as the `matrix` context only has the properties provided to it. You could set something like `continue-on-error: ${{ matrix.jdk != 11 }}`, so any job where `jdk` is *not* `11` can fail without cancelling the entire matrix.

Comment: Thanks again, i will try to work on the suggested logic.

Comment: I found the way to indexing. Job-index can do this magic. The index of the current job in the matrix. Note: This number is a zero-based number. The first job's index in the matrix is 0.
**continue-on-error: ${{ strategy.job-index != 0 }}**

Comment: @new_bie Ooooh it's on the `strategy` context, not `matrix`! Good find.

Answer (score 0):

**Motivation**: Benjamin's answer

One more generic solution would be using "**strategy**". Indexing in possible in strategy.job. The index of the current job in the matrix.

Note: This number is a zero-based number. The first job's index in the matrix is 0.

```
jobs:   
  gradle:
    continue-on-error: ${{ strategy.job-index != 0 }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        jdk: [11, 14]
    runs-on: [linux]

  steps:
    - name: Checkout Repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    ...
    - name: gradle Build
      uses: abc_workflow@v1
      with:
        java-version: ${{ matrix.jdk }}
```